python multithreading, running the same speed even when more than one threads are used
The code works perfectly, however when more than one threads are used I would expect it to run faster, for example if 2 threads are used it should go twice as fast but instead it takes the same amount of time to complete.
The bottle neck is between 'TRY 10' and 'TRY 20'. This is where it seems that even when using more threads it takes the same amount of speed regardless.
code is below
final_dfs_time = []

# Initialize a lock for synchronizing access to df_list_time
lock = threading.Lock()
json_list_lock = threading.Lock()

def append_to_dataframe(file_path):
    df_temp_time = None
    if os.path.getsize(file_path) > 0:
        try:
            print(f"try 1 {file_path}")
            # Read the JSON file using buffered I/O
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
                buffered_file = io.BufferedReader(file)
                json_list = json.load(buffered_file)
                print(f"try 2 {file_path}")

            # Initialize an empty list to store temporary DataFrames
            df_list_time = []

            print(f"try 10")


            for entry in json_list:  # Iterate over json_list, not json_data
                try:
                    with json_list_lock:
                        for epoch_time, values in entry.items():
                            # Create a Series for each key-value pair
                            
                            series = pd.Series(values, name=epoch_time)
                            
                            # Convert the series into a DataFrame
                            temp_df_time = series.to_frame().T.rename(columns=column_mapping)


                            
                            # Add 'time' column
                            # Convert epoch_time to a pandas Series with the same length as temp_df_time
                            epoch_time_series = pd.Series(epoch_time, index=temp_df_time.index)
                            # Assign the Series to the 'time' column directly
                            
                            temp_df_time['time'] = epoch_time_series
                            
                            # Acquire the lock before appending to df_list_time
                            with lock:
                                # print(f"LOCK {file_path}")
                                # Append the DataFrame to the list
                                
                                df_list_time.append(temp_df_time)
                                

                except ValueError as e:
                  print(f"Error reading {file_path}: {e}")



            print(f"TRY 20")


            # Concatenate the DataFrames into one DataFrame
            df_temp_time = pd.concat((df for df in df_list_time), ignore_index=True) #stuck here for 1
            print(f"try4 {file_path}")
            print(f"Appended {file_path} for user {user_id_dir}")

        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Error reading {file_path}: {e}")

    else:
        print(f"Skipping empty file: {file_path}")

    print(f"try5 {file_path}")
    return df_temp_time


num_threads = 5
# Create a ThreadPoolExecutor with the desired number of threads
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as executor:
    # Map the function to each file path and process concurrently
    results = executor.map(append_to_dataframe, file_paths)

# Concatenate all resulting DataFrames
final_dfs_time = list(results)

total_df_time = pd.concat(final_dfs_time, ignore_index=True)
print("all added together")

I have tried to see if this bottle neck was to do with input output overflow but it looks like it could be more of a time delay with actually converting it to a dataframe on the line of
temp_df_time = series.to_frame().T.rename(columns=column_mapping)
rather than
series = pd.Series(values, name=epoch_time)
but I am unsure on the true cause of this
Any help on would be great thanks

TL;DR: threads are not really concurrent in most python versions, there's a global interpreter lock. If you want speed, create processes

Why would you expect it to run faster? You're confusing multi-threading with multi-processing.

Does this answer your question? What is the global interpreter lock (GIL) in CPython?

In Python, threads will not run parallel due to the global interpreter lock (GIL). Instead of using threads, you can use processes. You can use the multiprocessing library instead of threading to create processes or use ProcessPoolExecutor instead of ThreadPoolExecutor, and other APIs are similar, like multiprocessing.Lock instead of threading.Lock. Also, using lock is not required as you are manipulating local variables (unique for every process in their stack) instead of global variables.
Here's your code version using multiprocessing.
Note: I am considering file_paths is list of unique paths of json file
final_dfs_time = []
def append_to_dataframe(file_path):
    df_temp_time = None
    if os.path.getsize(file_path) > 0:
        try:
            print(f"try 1 {file_path}")
            # Read the JSON file using buffered I/O
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
                buffered_file = io.BufferedReader(file)
                json_list = json.load(buffered_file)
                print(f"try 2 {file_path}")

            # Initialize an empty list to store temporary DataFrames
            df_list_time = []

            print(f"try 10")

            for entry in json_list:  # Iterate over json_list, not json_data
                try:
                    # No need to use lock here because of you is processing different json file for each process
                    for epoch_time, values in entry.items():
                        # Create a Series for each key-value pair

                        series = pd.Series(values, name=epoch_time)

                        # Convert the series into a DataFrame
                        temp_df_time = series.to_frame().T.rename(columns=column_mapping)

                        # Add 'time' column
                        # Convert epoch_time to a pandas Series with the same length as temp_df_time
                        temp_df_time['time'] = pd.Series(epoch_time, index=temp_df_time.index)

                        # Also no need to acquire lock here because you are appending in local variable instead of global
                        df_list_time.append(temp_df_time)

                except ValueError as e:
                    print(f"Error reading {file_path}: {e}")

            print(f"TRY 20")

            # Concatenate the DataFrames into one DataFrame
            df_temp_time = pd.concat((df for df in df_list_time), ignore_index=True)  # stuck here for 1
            print(f"try4 {file_path}")
            print(f"Appended {file_path} for user {user_id_dir}")

        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Error reading {file_path}: {e}")

    else:
        print(f"Skipping empty file: {file_path}")

    print(f"try5 {file_path}")
    return df_temp_time


num_process = os.cpu_count() - 1
# Create a ProcessPoolExecutor with the desired number of processes
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_process) as executor:
    # Map the function to each file path and process concurrently
    results = executor.map(append_to_dataframe, file_paths)

# Concatenate all resulting DataFrames
final_dfs_time = list(results)

total_df_time = pd.concat(final_dfs_time, ignore_index=True)
print("all added together")

